# how can i include image from front end of template using wordpress and php

Tags: php, wordpress

In this piece of code, an empty file is getting stored in upload folder, but not a proper image file attached. I don't know why.

I'm also not getting the proper usage of `wp_upload_bits`, it writes a file in upload folder. I don't know how to change that to suite it for the uploading of an image.

I'm totally confused with the error in my code.

I know that there are multiple duplicate question related to it in stack overflow, but I'm not getting a proper result while using the solution described there. Please help me to find a solution.

My piece of code is as follows:

```
$upload = wp_upload_bits( $_FILES['file']['name'], null, file_get_contents( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) );

$wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype( basename( $upload['file'] ), null );

$wp_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();

$attachment = array(
    'guid' => $upload['url'] ,
    'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
    'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename( $upload['file'] )),
    'post_content'   => '',
    'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    );

$attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $upload['file'],  $post_id);

require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');

$attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $upload['file'] );
wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

update_post_meta( $post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id );

set_post_thumbnail(  $post_id, $attach_id );
```

While using this code,attach file is getting stored in WordPress DB, but not in upload folder (media library).

I'm new to WordPress, so I am unable to find a solution for the reason of not storing a proper attached image file in upload folder.